# What is the efficient way to check if kwargs are valid then pass them accordingly?

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I have the following code and what I need to do is to check if either `status`, `issue`, `owner` and `mantis_id` are valid (not empty). According to the validity result I pass all those that are valid as kwargs to a function called `upsert()`.

```
form=ticket_form()
status=request.form['status']
issue=request.form['ticket_issue']
owner=request.form['owner']
mantis_id=request.form['mantis_id']
```

Here is the second part where I pass those arguments that are valid as kwargs:

```
cur.execute(upsert('tbl_tickets', status=status, issue=issue, owner=owner))
connect.commit()
```

I can check each of them individually but I was wondering if there is a more efficient/compact way that I can use. Thanks.

Comment: What value would they have if they are empty? `None`?

Comment: @ChristianDean If they are empty, I simply don't need to pass them to upsert(). Because if they are empty I don't want to change the existing value in database. So I'll keep whatever is in there as long as there isn't any update. Hope that helps.

Comment: I understand that. I'm asking you what value represents their "emptiness"? Will they have a value of `None` if they are empty. Will they be an `empty` list?

Comment: `issue` and `owner` are empty strings, `""`, `status` and `mantis_id` are `None`.

Comment: Ah, thanks. That's the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
all_args = dict(
    form=ticket_form()
    status=request.form['status']
    issue=request.form['ticket_issue']
    owner=request.form['owner']
    mantis_id=request.form['mantis_id']
)
valid_args = {k: v for k, v in all_args.items() if v}
cur.execute(upsert('tbl_tickets', **valid_args))
```